# How to sum column values with string in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

How sum only part of numbers in Google sheet column?
20+20+60 = 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SPLIT()` then `SUM()`. Try-

```
=SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(B4:B6," "),,1))
```

[image]